# Getting a split out of a string into a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a data.frame trying to extract a part of a string between **`,`** and **`.`** and putting that into a neww column. I would like to use dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)

name <- c("Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley","Heikkinen, Miss. Laina","Moran, Mr. James","Allen, Mr. William Henry","Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)")
sex <- c("female","female","male","male","female")
age <- c(22,23,24,37,42)
data <- data.frame(name,sex,age)
```

So I want to extract Mrs, Misss, Mr and so on into a own column.

```
data %>%
  mutate(title = strsplit(name, split = "[,.]")) %>%
  select(name,title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete everything outside `,.` using `gsub(".*, |\\..*", "", name)`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(title = gsub(".*, |\\..*", "", name))
```

[image]

`gsub(".*, ", "", name)`: deletes everything before `,`, `,` itself and space after. 
`gsub("\\..*", "", name)`: deletes `.` and everything after it.
`|` combines two gsub patterns.

Comment: Please include any packages used

Comment: @Sotos Thanks, happens

Answer (score 2):

`str_extract` will retrieve the first instance within each string:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(name,sex,age) %>% 
  mutate(title = str_extract(name, ",.+\\."),
         title = str_replace_all(title, "([[:punct:]]| )", ""))
```

A slightly more efficient solution:

```
data %>% 
      mutate(title = str_trim(str_extract(name, regex("(?<=,).*?(?=\\.)"))))
```

The `(?<=,)` says to look after a comma, the `(?=\\.)` says to look before the period, and the `.*?` says grab everything in between.  the `str_trim` removes the leading and trailing white space.

Comment: Please include any packages you are using

Comment: `str_replace_all` removes the punctuation and the white space. Depending on what I'm doing, I sometimes break these problems into smaller steps so I can better understand what actions I'm taking (a style choice I make because I don't enjoy working through more complex regular expressions :) )

Comment: @Sotos done.  I got sloppy since they were both declared in the problem where the sample data was defined.

Answer (score 1):

Im having no answer to the dplyr problem.

I just wanted to mention, that this way of splitting the salutation from a name is a way which will probably encounter multiple errors when using real world data.

A better (but still error-prone) way to do this is by creating a lookup table for common salutations while utilizing on regex.

The advantage over splitting the data lies within the fact that if there is no hit in the regex, it remains empty (NA) and can easily be fixed manually, but does not create inconsistent data in the first step.

Comment: This is a good point. You should add some example code to illustrate the regex-lookup table methodology.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any external package

```
data$title <- with(data, sub("^[^,]+,\\s*(\\S+).*", "\\1", name))
data$title
#[1] "Mrs."  "Miss." "Mr."   "Mr."   "Mrs."
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Benjamin's answer (Base R's equivalent to `str_extract_all`), here's how to do it using `regmatches` + `gregexpr` + positive lookahead:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(title = regmatches(data$name, gregexpr("\\b[[:alpha:]]+(?=[.])", 
                                                data$name, perl = TRUE))) %>%
  select(name,title)
```

Result:

```
                                          name title
1                   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley   Mrs
2                       Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  Miss
3                             Moran, Mr. James    Mr
4                     Allen, Mr. William Henry    Mr
5 Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)   Mrs
```

`\\b` matches a "word boundary", which in this case is a space. `perl = TRUE` is needed to utilize positive lookahead `(?=[.])`, which essentially says "only if the pattern is followed by a `.`"

Answer (score 0):

guess something like this: `data %>% mutate(title = gsub(".*, |\\..*", "", name))`